# Prove the existence of a non-integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$. Prove that there exists $t \in [0,1]$ such that $\frac{1}{|t-f(x)|}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

This is an interesting problem but I have no idea at all. Any hints would be appreciated.

**Edit**:
Here are some of my attempts. First I noticed that if $\{x:f(x)=t\}$ is of positive measure, then clearly it is done. While this may not hapen, I tried to consider the set $\{x:|f(x)-t|<c\}$ instead. I also tried Chebyshev's inequality. But these seem to be of no use.

Comment: Sorry about that. I do have some thoughts but they seem to be of no use. Here are some of my attempts. First I noticed that if {x:f(x)=t} is of positive measure, then clearly it is done. While this  may not hapen, I tried to consider the set {x:|f(x)-t|<c} instead. I also tried Chebyshev's inequality. But I can't find all these useful.

Comment: I see that 1/|t-f(x)| is not integrable w.r.t t and x, since it is not integrable w.r.t. t for every fixed x. But how can I conclude that it is not integrable w.r.t x for some t?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way that goes back to basics: For each positive integer $k$, divide the interval $[0,1]$ (which is the target set of $f$) into $2^k$ equal length disjoint intervals.  Let $$I_i(k)=[a_i(k),b_i(k)) \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., 2^k\}$$
denote the particular intervals (the last interval has the form $[a_{2^k}(k), b_{2^k}(k)]$). Now:

- For $k=1$ we have $I_1(1)=[0, 1/2), I_2(1)=[1/2,1]$. Let $i^*(1) \in \{1,2\}$ denote the index $i$ that satisfies
  $$\mu\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\in I_{i}\} \geq 1/2$$
  (if there are ties, choose the smallest such $i$). Let $I^*(1)$ denote the corresonding interval $I_i(k)$ for $i=i^*(k)$.
- For $k=2$, chop interval $I^*(1)$ in two and choose the half that has at least half the probability, call that $i^*(2)\in\{1, ..., 4\}$ and let $I^*(2)$ denote the corresponding interval. Then
  $$ \mu\{x\in [0,1]: f(x) \in I^*(2)\} \geq 1/4$$
- We proceed with nested intervals
  $$ I^*(1)\supseteq I^*(2)\supseteq I^*(3)...$$
  such that for all $k$ we have $|I^*(k)|=1/2^k$ and
  $$ \mu\{x\in[0,1]:f(x) \in I^*(k)\} \geq 1/2^k \quad (Eq. *)$$
  We now use the nested interval theorem, which (unfortunately) requires closed intervals, so let us take the closure $\overline{I}^*(k)$. The nested interval theorem implies there exists a point $t \in \cap_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline{I}^*(k)$.

As a minor cosmetic issue, we want to say $t$ is in all the intervals $I^*(k)$, but we can only say it is in all intervals $\overline{I}^*(k)$. So we redefine for each $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and each $i\in\{1, ..., 2^k\}$ new intervals $D_i(k)$ that again partition $[0,1]$ into disjoint intervals of length $1/2^k$, such that for each $i \in \{1, ..., 2^k\}$ we have
$$ D_{i}(k) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
I_i(k) & \mbox{ if $i \notin \{i^*(k), i^*(k)+1\}$} \\
\overline{I}^*(k) & \mbox{ if $i=i^*(k)$}\\
(a_i(k),b_i(k)) & \mbox{ if $i=i^*(k)+1$} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
and call $D^*(k)=I^*(k)$. This simply ensures:

**Property 1:**  $t \in D^*(k)$ for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

**Property 2:** $\mu\{x \in [0,1]: f(x)\in D^*(k)\}\geq 1/2^k$ for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Note that Property 2 follows from (Eq. *) because $I^*(k)\subseteq D^*(k)$.

---

Now assume
$$ \int \frac{1}{|t-f(x)|}dx<\infty$$
(we reach a contradiction). Define $S=\{x \in [0,1]: f(x)\neq t\}$. and observe that $\mu\{S\}=1$. Define $h:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by
$$ h(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{|t-f(x)|} & \mbox{if $x \in S$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$
Since $h(x)=1/|t-f(x)|$ for almost all $x \in [0,1]$, we have
$$\int_0^1 h(x)dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{|t-f(x)|}dx$$
Let us construct a simple function: For each $k\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and each $i \in \{1, ..., 2^k\}$ define
$$v_i(k) = \inf_{y \in D_i(k)} \frac{1}{|t-y|}$$
Observe that
$$v_{i^*(k)}(k)\geq 2^{k} \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\} \quad (Eq. **)$$
Then define
$$g_k(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^k}v_i(k)1_{\{x \in D_i(k)\cap S\}}\quad \forall x \in [0,1]$$
$$ \tilde{g}_k(x) = \sum_{i \in \{1, ..., 2^k\}\setminus i^*(k)}v_i(k)1_{\{x \in D_i(k)\cap S\}}\quad \forall x \in [0,1]$$
We get
$$ 0\leq \tilde{g}_k(x)\leq g_k(x)\leq h(x)\quad \forall x \in S$$
Further
$$ \tilde{g}_k\nearrow h $$
so
$$ \sum_{i \in \{1, ..., 2^j\}\setminus i^*(k)}v_i(k)\mu\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)\in D_i(k)\} \nearrow \int h$$
However, since $\tilde{g}_k\leq g_k\leq h$ we have $\int \tilde{g}_k\leq \int g_k\leq \int h$ and in particular, since $\int h<\infty$, we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left[(\int g_k)-(\int \tilde{g}_k)\right] = 0$. So
$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}v_{i^*(k)}(k)\mu\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\in D^*(k)\}= 0$$
On the other hand we know for all $k\in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ that
$$ v_{i^*(k)}(k)\mu\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\in D^*(k)\} \geq 2^k\frac{1}{2^k}=1$$
where we have used Property 2 and (Eq **). This is a contradiction. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

First observe that by the Fubini-Tonelli theorem,

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1  \frac{1}{|t-f(x)|} dx dt = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{|t-f(x)|} dt dx = \infty$$

The inner integral on the right diverges logarithmically for each fixed $x$ in view of $f(x) \in [0,1]$. Hence, $\int_0^1  \frac{1}{|t-f(x)|} dx$ is unbounded as a function of $t$ (since its integral over a finite measure set diverges).

EDIT: As Michael pointed out, this doesn’t guarantee a $t$ for which the integral diverges.

Comment: I thought about this before doing my own answer, but it does not seem to work. Just because a function is unbounded does not mean it takes the value $\infty$ somewhere. Specifically, just because $\int_0^1 h(t)dt=\infty$ does not mean there exists a $t \in [0,1]$ such that $h(t)=\infty$. For example take $h:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ with $h(t)=1/t$ for $t\neq 0$, $h(0)=0$.

Comment: Nevertheless you can indeed say that if $g:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is unbounded then there is a $t^*\in [0,1]$ and a collection of points $\{t_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $t_i\rightarrow t^*$ and  $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} g(t_i)=\infty$.

Comment: You’re right, but in this case I think Fatou’s lemma should fix that issue: take $t_n$ such that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|t_n-f(x)|} dx > n$, extract a subsequence converging to $t^*$, then since the integrands converge a.e. to $\frac{1}{|t^*-f(x)|}$, Fatou’s lemma yields $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|t^*-f(x)|} dx \geq \sup_n \int_0^1 \frac{1}{|t_n-f(x)|} dx = \infty$

Comment: Apologies, after the last inequality should be a limsup (here they’re the same of course)

Comment: Fatou's lemma deals with $\liminf$, and the inequality goes the other way, which does not seem helpful in this context.

Comment: There’s a reverse Fatou lemma which does indeed deal with limsup and in which the inequality is as stated (see wikipedia, “reverse fatou lemma”). But it seems I forgot an assumption, namely that the sequence of integrands have an integrable dominating function. I will think more about this.

Comment: If you assume $\int 1/|t^*-f(x)|dx<\infty$ (for the sake of contradiction) you might use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, but unfortunately it does not seem like $1/|t^*-f(x)|\geq 1/|t_n-f(x)|$ for all $x$, so it is integrable but may not be a valid dominating function.